# Reader does not stop in my program (java)

Tags: java, arrays, class, java.util.scanner

I am still fairly new to java and in my current class project we are trying to set students to classrooms, the students information is read from a text file which we create but my reader program does not stop after 4 lines (which is the end of the information of the student). It reads through all of them and prints them before analyzing what they have to be able to put them in the correct `classRoom`. Please remember I am still new to java.

Also not sure about an error I keep getting about `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found`

this is my reader program

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Student{

    private Scanner file;
    public String name;
    public String id;
    public String year;
    public String course;
    //open the file to read
    public void openFile(){
      try{
          file = new Scanner(new File("StudentFile.txt"));
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          System.out.print("Could not Open File");
      }
    }
    //Read the file and Assign the Student information strings
    protected void readFileText(){
        if(file.hasNext())
        {          
           for(int n=0; n<4; n++)
           {
                name = file.nextLine();
                id = file.nextLine();
                year = file.nextLine();
                course = file.nextLine();
                System.out.print("\n" + name + "\n" + id + "\n" + year + "\n" + course + "\n");
           }
        }   
        else
        {
             name = null;
        }
    }
    //close the file 
    public void closeFile(){
        file.close();
    }


    //set information

    public Student(){
          this.name = name;
          this.id = id;
          this.year = year;
          this.course = course;
    }


    //Get the informaton to main method

    public String getName(){
      return name;
    }

    public String getId(){
      return id;
    }
    public String getYear(){
      return year;
    }
    public String getCourse(){
      return course;
    }

}
```

This is my main method

```
    public class Registrar {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
          Student student = new Student();
          student.openFile();

          String namenull = " ";
          String classRoom[] = {"Washington W1000", "Washington W1100", "Washington W1200", "Washington W1300", "Washington W1400", "Washington W1500", "Kennedy K1000", "Kennedy K1100", "Kennedy K1200", "Kennedy K1300"};
          int maxCapacity = 25;
          int studentNum = 0;
          int num = 0;
          int n = 0;
          String currentClass = classRoom[0];

          while(namenull != null){      // to read the file and set students to a classroom.
             student.readFileText();
             String course = student.getCourse();
                while (n < 10){
                   if(currentClass == "Washington W1400"){

                      maxCapacity = 30;
                   }
                   else if(currentClass == "Kennedy 1000"){
                      maxCapacity = 25;
                   }
                   else if(currentClass == "Kennedy 1200"){
                      maxCapacity = 35;
                   }
                   int num1 = 1;
                   int num2 = 2;
                   int num3 = 3;
                   if(studentNum < maxCapacity && course == "Comp 182" && num < 10){
                            System.out.print("\nRegistered in Comp 182, in classroom " + currentClass);
                            studentNum++;
                    }
                    else{
                               while(num == num1 || num == num2 || num == num3 || num == num){
                                     num = num++;
                               }
                     }
                    if(studentNum < maxCapacity && course == "Comp 182 Lab" && num1 < 10){
                            currentClass = classRoom[num1];
                            System.out.print("\nRegistered in Comp 182 Lab, in classroom " + currentClass);
                            studentNum++;
                     }
                     else{
                              while(num1 == num || num1 == num2 || num1 == num3 || num1 == num1){
                                   num1 = num1++;
                              }
                     }
                     if(studentNum < maxCapacity && course == "Comp 101" && num2 < 10){
                            currentClass = classRoom[num2];
                            System.out.print("\nRegistered in Comp 101, in classroom " + currentClass);
                            studentNum++;
                            }
                    else{
                             while(num2 == num || num2 == num1 || num2 == num3 || num2 == num2){
                                    num2 = num2++;
                             }
                    }
                    if(studentNum < maxCapacity && course == "Comp 101 Lab" && num3 <10){
                            currentClass = classRoom[num3];
                            System.out.print("\nRegistered in Comp 101 Lab, in classroom " + currentClass);
                            studentNum++;
                    }
                    else{
                          while(num3 == num || num3 == num1 || num3 == num2 || num3 == num3){
                              num3 = num3++;
                          }
                    }    
                    currentClass = classRoom[num];
                 }
                 namenull = student.getName();
            }
            student.closeFile(); 
        }
}
```

As Requested, my StudentFile.txt

```
Alfredo Dominguez
1205586453
Freshman
Comp 182
Stacy Flores
6584527256
Sophmore
Comp 182 Lab
```

Comment: It's very hard to read your code, for you and for us, simply because it's not preoperly indented. Please fix that.

Comment: How do you know your program does not stop after 4 lines for a given student? Is this an assumption you are making because you get the NoSuchElementException? 


Its originating from one of your calls to nextLine(). There are 4 of them executed back-to-back in a for loop in readFileText(). In other words, you are *always* going to get this exception if the number of lines in your file isn't a multiple of four.


I think it would be helpful if you showed us your input file, and restated your question.

Answer (score 1):

Scanner throws NoSuchElementException if no line was found. so wrap each `file.nextLine();` with

```
if(file.hasNextLine()){

 file.nextLine();

}
```

Comment: Tried this, it only prints out 1 student now and gives me the same `Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found` after